# Link static library in a static library project with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019, static-libraries, static-linking

I want to link in my "static library" configuration project a static library with cmake in Visual Studio.

Following [cmake guide](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/guide/importing-exporting/index.html):

```
add_library(bar SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET bar PROPERTY
             IMPORTED_IMPLIB "c:/path/to/bar.lib")
add_executable(myexe src1.c src2.c)
target_link_libraries(myexe PRIVATE bar)
```

but in Visual Studio the project properties:
`Configuration Properties->Librarian->General->Additional Dependencies`
and
`Configuration Properties->Librarian->General->Additional Library Directories`

are both empty.

Comment: If it's a static library, you wouldn't use `IMPORTED_IMPLIB`, but `IMPORTED_LOCATION`. Implibs are for DLLs.

Comment: I've tried ```add_library(foo STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY
             IMPORTED_LOCATION "/path/to/libfoo.a")``` but does not work

Comment: In case of proper STATIC IMPORTED library does "does not work" mean that the project is configured successfully but you don't see the library in the project's properties? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: The project is configured successfully but I don't see the library in the project's properties